# Get the newly created element as a jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I'm inserting a *single* new element using the following code:

```
$('#myID').before('<tr><td>New Row</td></tr>');
```

I want to get the *"newly inserted row"* as a jQuery object. How may I do that?

Comment: The function of `before()` is capable of inserting the provided argument multiple times where the "selector" matches; Furthermore, the provided argument is a _single_ element that happens to have some children :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way of achieving it:

```
var newRow = $('<tr><td>New Row</td></tr>')
$('#myID').before(newRow);
```

Or you can do it this way, using `insertBefore`:

```
var newRow = $('<tr><td>New Row</td></tr>').insertBefore('#myID');
```

Comment: This is pretty nice :) I just thought of [`$('#myID').prev();`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) as another solution! Thank you :)